# Post an empty body to REST API via HttpClient

Tags: c#, wcf, httpclient, wcf-web-api

The API I'm trying to call requires a POST with an empty body. I'm using the WCF Web API HttpClient, and I can't find the right code that will post with an empty body. I found references to some HttpContent.CreateEmpty() method, but I don't think it’s for the Web API HttpClient code since I can't seem to find that method.

Comment: HttpContent.CreateEmpty was from the old HttpClient prototype that was part of REST Starter kit.  Unfortunately there is no equivalent in the new HttpClient.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set up HttpContent for my HttpClient PostAsync second parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18971510/how-do-i-set-up-httpcontent-for-my-httpclient-postasync-second-parameter)

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim If there was a hole in the space time continuum and somehow 2013 came before 2011, then yes it is a possible duplicate.

Comment: "Possible duplicate" is a way to clean-up - to close similar questions and keep one with the best answers. The date is not essential. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha If you agree that it requires clarification please vote on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281980/add-clarification-link-to-possible-duplicate-automated-comment

Answer (score 277, accepted):

Use `StringContent` or `ObjectContent` which derive from `HttpContent` or you can use `null` as `HttpContent`:

```
var response = await client.PostAsync(requestUri, null);
```

Comment: It looks like this is only in .NET framework 4.5?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.stringcontent(v=VS.110).aspx

Comment: It will ship with WCF Web API but I think some of the "good parts" will make it into the framework itself.

Comment: Why isn't there any overload methods which does not require a `HttpContent` class? Should we at least provide something (even an empty string) to make a http post?

Comment: You can use `null` as the `HttpContent`, this will send no body in the request, e.g. `var response = await client.PostAsync(requestUri, null);`

Comment: @OwainWilliams said the same as the original answer, but this comment got way more upvotes as it's straight to the point, for me, boosted the confidence  ;)

Comment: Assembly `System.Net.Http` in version 5.0.0.0 has still no nullable `HttpContent` parameter, so `null` should be not allowed. But it (still) seems to work. I could pass `null!`.

Comment: C# 8.0 introduced [nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references), before that _all_ reference types could be `null`. I assume the public `HttpContent` parameters in the [`HttpClient`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v5.0.5/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs) have not been explicitly declared as non-nullable to maintain backwards compatibility with older C# versions. I can't see anything in the code that implies the `HttpContent` cannot be `null`, which I interpret to mean that `null` _**is**_ allowed.

Comment: @OwainWilliams in case you do not want to use null there, feel free to call like that: httpClient.PostAsync(uri, new StringContent(String.Empty)).

Comment: for me I don't need to put a body, but need to add some header then use StringContent was ok, you can create a content with string.empty and put there the header that you want

Answer (score 134):

Did this before, just keep it simple:

```
Task<HttpResponseMessage> task = client.PostAsync(url, null);
```

Comment: This is cleaner than accepted answer, and should be voted up.

Answer (score 11):

Have found that:

```
Task<HttpResponseMessage> task = client.PostAsync(url, null);
```

Adds null to the request body, which failed on WSO2. Replaced with:

```
Task<HttpResponseMessage> task = client.PostAsync(url, new {});
```

And worked.

Comment: I cannot confirm this finding (but I am not sure my test was totally adequate). When I POST to one of my own APIs with a `null` content and look at the content found in the `HttpRequestMessage`, I seem to be getting a length of zero bytes.

Answer (score 3):

In case you do not want to pass `null` value you can you the following:

```
Task<HttpResponseMessage> task = httpClient.PostAsync(uri, new StringContent(String.Empty));
```

But, beside this, as above already discussed you could pass `null` in there as a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this problem, use this example:

```
   using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var stringContent = new StringContent(string.Empty);
                stringContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                var response = client.PostAsync(url, stringContent).Result;
                var result = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<model>().Result;
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to avoid 'null' and make your intentions clear, as do I, you can override the StringContent class:

```
    private sealed class DeliberatelyEmptyContent : StringContent
    {
        public DeliberatelyEmptyContent() : base(string.Empty)
        {
        }
    }

    public async Task ActivateUser(string xflowUserId)
    {
        var httpclient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient(_namedHttpClientName);
        string activateUrl = $"/User/{xflowUserId}/Activate";

        _ = await httpclient.PutAsync(activateUrl, new DeliberatelyEmptyContent());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send an empty object too:

```
var emptyObject = new object();
HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await server.CreateClient().PutAsJsonAsync(Put.SomeUrl(), emptyObject);
```

Answer (score -6):

I think it does that automagically if your web method has no parameters or they all fit into URL template.

For example this declaration sends empty body:

```
  [OperationContract]
  [WebGet(UriTemplate = "mykewlservice/{emailAddress}",
     RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
     BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
  void GetStatus(string emailAddress, out long statusMask);
```

Comment: I'm trying to SEND an empty body.  The HttpClient.Post() method requires an URI and a HttpContent object.  I'm not what to pass as the HttpContent when I don't want to send anything.

Comment: So you're not using WCF. That's even easier:
...
         HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("http://...");
         request.Method = "POST";
         HttpWebResponse respose = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

...
you result in response

Comment: I'm using HttpClient, not HttpWebRequest.  Using StringContent with an empty string worked.