# How do I set up HttpContent for my HttpClient PostAsync second parameter?

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient, httpcontent

```
public static async Task<string> GetData(string url, string data)
{
    UriBuilder fullUri = new UriBuilder(url);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
        fullUri.Query = data;

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(new Uri(url), /*expects HttpContent*/);

    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    return responseBody;
}
```

The `PostAsync` takes another parameter that needs to be `HttpContent`.

How do I set up an `HttpContent`? There Is no documentation anywhere that works for Windows Phone 8.

If I do `GetAsync`, it works great! but it needs to be POST with the content of key="bla", something="yay"

**//EDIT**

Thanks so much for the answer... This works well, but still a few unsures here:

```
    public static async Task<string> GetData(string url, string data)
    {
        data = "test=something";

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        StringContent queryString = new StringContent(data);

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(new Uri(url), queryString );

        //response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return responseBody;
    }
```

The data "test=something" I assumed would pick up on the api side as post data "test", evidently it does not. On another matter, I may need to post entire objects/arrays through post data, so I assume json will be best to do so. Any thoughts on how I get post data through?

Perhaps something like:

```
class SomeSubData
{
    public string line1 { get; set; }
    public string line2 { get; set; }
}

class PostData
{
    public string test { get; set; }
    public SomeSubData lines { get; set; }
}

PostData data = new PostData { 
    test = "something",
    lines = new SomeSubData {
        line1 = "a line",
        line2 = "a second line"
    }
}
StringContent queryString = new StringContent(data); // But obviously that won't work
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't find how to use HttpContent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145053/cant-find-how-to-use-httpcontent)

Answer (score 227, accepted):

This is answered in some of the answers to [Can't find how to use HttpContent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145053) as well as in this [blog post](http://pfelix.wordpress.com/2012/01/16/the-new-system-net-http-classes-message-content/).

In summary, you can't directly set up an instance of `HttpContent` because it is an *abstract class*. You need to use one the classes derived from it depending on your need. Most likely `StringContent`, which lets you set the string value of the response, the encoding, and the media type in the constructor. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.stringcontent.aspx

Comment: I'll check this out. I think when I find this out, i'm going to have to put this somewhere where everyone can see it! This has had me going for 4 days now, trying to get a simple REST to an API.

Comment: The StringContent worked great, but actually, can't get the PostData to get through to the site i'm calling now :D. I'll edit question to show you what I now currently have

Comment: A quick answer to "how do i post a JSON reprsentation of my class" is "serialize the object to JSON, probably with JSON.Net", but that really belongs in a separate question.

Answer (score 154):

To add to Preston's answer, here's the complete list of the `HttpContent` derived classes available in the standard library:

[image: Credit: https://pfelix.wordpress.com/2012/01/16/the-new-system-net-http-classes-message-content/]

**Credit**: https://pfelix.wordpress.com/2012/01/16/the-new-system-net-http-classes-message-content/

There's also a supposed `ObjectContent` but I was unable to find it in `ASP.NET Core`.

Of course, you could skip the whole `HttpContent` thing all together with `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` extensions (you'll have to do an import to get it to work in ASP.NET Core for now: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1558) and then you can do things like:

```
var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("AddNewArticle", new Article
{
    Title = "New Article Title",
    Body = "New Article Body"
});
```

**Update**:
For framework versions 5+, via:

```
using System.Net.Http.Json
```

Without any imports, you can just use use:

```
await client.PostAsJsonAsync("url", new { });
```

Comment: Most comprehensive answer.. very neat and clean way to achieve apparently complicated task.

Comment: I like the re-use of what Microsoft already has, plus it makes the code so much less and clean.

Answer (score 43):

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        apiTable table = new apiTable();
        table.Name = "Zainab Nazakat";
        table.Roll = "6655";

        string str = "";
        string str2 = "";

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(table);   //using Newtonsoft.Json

        StringContent httpContent = new StringContent(json, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var response = await client.PostAsync("http://YourSite.com/api/apiTables", httpContent);

        str = "" + response.Content + " : " + response.StatusCode;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {       
            str2 = "Data Posted";
        }

        return View();
    }
```