# Invalid content type format in c# http request

Tags: c#, http

I am trying to set a content type of this:

> System.FormatException: 'The format of value 'multipart/form-data;boundary=ce4da8a9-0e0d-4ba6-9f00-e7f3b002a717' is invalid.'

when executing this

```
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri)
{
    Content = new StringContent(postData, Encoding.UTF8, content_type) // CONTENT-TYPE header
};
```

but according to this

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/ucwa/batchingrequests
https://ucwa.skype.com/documentation/Resources-batch-3
https://ucwa.skype.com/documentation/ProgrammingConcepts-Batch

All the resources say to use the format that I have. And it doesn't complain about this in Postman too. Is there a way I can force this content type in the `StringContent` in c#?

There is an answer here

[How do I send arbitrary JSON data, with a custom header, to a REST server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21057354/how-do-i-send-arbitrary-json-data-with-a-custom-header-to-a-rest-server)

but I'm not sure how to implement this.

Comment: I tried putting the answer from the link, but it says `__DynamicallyInvokable` is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

The answer s/b somewhat obvious from the error message.  `"multipart/form-data;boundary=ce4da8a9-0e0d-4ba6-9f00-e7f3b002a717"` is not a valid content type. Even if you were creating a custom content type, you are prohibited from using the following characters:

```
( ) @ < > , ; : \ " / [ ] ? = { }
```

The presence of any of these in your content type will cause

```
StringContent(postData, Encoding.UTF8, content_type)
```

to fail with a `System.FormatException`

Comment: How can I attach this custom content type then? If I can send this in postman, there should be a way in c#?

Comment: I don’t believe the boundary info should be part of the content type.