# POST to ASP.NET WebApi 2 in .NET 4.5.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, httpclient, asp.net-web-api2

How can I POST a complex type to a Web Api 2 controller action, from a C# client?
I see a lot of information about it but for older versions of the framework. What's the correct way to do it in .NET 4.5.1?

At the moment I have:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:60892/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    //client.PostAsJsonAsync() doesn't seem to exist or I am missing something
    //client.PostAsync() can't find a way to post a complex type    

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find the **PostAsJsonAsync** extension method in the [Micorosft ASP.NET Web API 2.1 Client NuGet package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/5.1.2).

Nevertheless, if you set the **HttpContent** appropriately the **PostAsync** method should work. An example can be found in [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18971510/how-do-i-set-up-httpcontent-for-my-httpclient-postasync-second-parameter).

Comment: So, yeah, I was missing the 2.1 Client nuget package. Thanks for the reply!