# C# - Body content in POST request

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api

I need to make some api calls in C#. I'm using Web API Client from Microsoft to do that. I success to make some POST requests, but I don't know how to add the field "Body" into my requests. Any idea ?
Here's my code:

```
    static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    public override void AwakeFromNib()
    {
        base.AwakeFromNib();
        notif_button.Activated += (sender, e) => {
        };
        tips_button.Activated += (sender, e) =>
        {
            Tip t1 = new Tip(title_tips.StringValue, pic_tips.StringValue, content_tips.StringValue, "TEST");
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("my_url");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            CreateProductAsync(t1).Wait();
        };
    }

    static async Task<Uri> CreateProductAsync(Tip tips)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/add_tips", tips);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        return response.Headers.Location;
    }
```

Comment: Don't add an answer to your question, post  a self-answer instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to [this](https://d-fens.ch/2014/04/12/httpclient-and-how-to-use-headers-content-type-and-postasync/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43158250/how-to-post-using-httpclient-content-type-application-x-www-form-urlencoded), I finally found the solution to send post requests with headers AND body content. Here's the code:

```
        var cl = new HttpClient();
        cl.BaseAddress = new Uri("< YOUR URL >");
        int _TimeoutSec = 90;
        cl.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, _TimeoutSec);
        string _ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        cl.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(key, value);
        cl.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(_ContentType));
        cl.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("key", "value");
        cl.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("key", "value");
        var _UserAgent = "d-fens HttpClient";
        cl.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", _UserAgent);

        var nvc = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        nvc.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("key of content", "value"));
        var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://www.t-lab.fr:3000/add_tips") { Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(nvc) };
        var res = cl.SendAsync(req);
```

Comment: List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>(); could be a dicionary      var payload = new Dictionary<string,string>()
        {
            {"grant_type", GoogleAuthGrantType},
            {"assertion", googleAuthJwt}
        };

Answer (score 24):

Step 1. Choose a type that derives from [HttpContent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpcontent(v=vs.118).aspx). If you want to write a lot of content with runtime code, you could use a [StreamContent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.streamcontent(v=vs.118).aspx) and open some sort of StreamWriter on it. For something short, use [StringContent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.stringcontent(v=vs.118).aspx).  You can also derive your own class for custom content.

Step 2. Pass the content in a call to [HttpClient.PostAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138190(v=vs.118).aspx).

Here's an example that uses StringContent to pass some JSON:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(someObject);
var httpContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var httpResponse = await httpClient.PostAsync("http://www.foo.bar", httpContent);
```

See also [How do I set up HttpContent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18971510/how-do-i-set-up-httpcontent-for-my-httpclient-postasync-second-parameter).

Comment: Thans for your answer. I think I didn't understood well. In fact, I replace in your code "someObject" by "tips", but it still doesn't work. Can you explain it or detail it ? I need to post headers and body. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

a little more understandable

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "*/*");

    var Parameters = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Id", "1"),
    };

    var Request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "Post_Url")
    {
        Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(Parameters)
    };

    var Result = client.SendAsync(Request).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```