# POST an empty body via HTTP Client

Tags: c#, .net, post, httpclient

I am trying to send an empty body to a `Post Request` but it does not execute.

I have already tried this:

[Post an empty body to REST API via HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7907648/post-an-empty-body-to-rest-api-via-httpclient/7908243#comment51588834_7908243)

```
    static async Task<string> CancelSale(string mainUrl, string bearerInfo,string systemNumber)
    {
        var cancelsaleUrl = mainUrl + $"api/sale/cancel/{systemNumber}";
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", bearerInfo);
        var data = new StringContent(null, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");            
        var saleResponse = await client.PostAsync(cancelsaleUrl, data);
        var responseBody = await saleResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(responseBody);

        return responseBody;
    }
```

But it just does not execute, no exception.

I also tried this :

```
        var saleResponse = await client.PostAsync(cancelsaleUrl, null);
```

which also does the same result.

Any ideas?

Comment: So when you debug through that it goes successfully through every line but the POST is never done?

Comment: At the moment it reaches data and leaves the method.
If I use the second option it leaves the method after saleResponse. And yes it does not do the POST

Answer (score 0):

The problem was very simple. I had the result of whole this method in a variable and It did not await the method:

```
        var cancelSale = CancelSale(mainUrl, bearerInfo, systemNumber);
```

Once it reaches anything that awaits it stops and leaves the method.

Here is the working code:

```
        var cancelSale = await CancelSale(mainUrl, bearerInfo, systemNumber);

        static async Task<string> CancelSale(string mainUrl, string bearerInfo,string systemNumber)
        {
        var cancelsaleUrl = mainUrl + $"api/sale/cancel/{systemNumber}";
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", bearerInfo);
        var saleResponse = await client.PostAsync(cancelsaleUrl, null);
        var responseBody = await saleResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
        return responseBody;
        }
```