# Why does HttpClient.PostAsync appear to be sending the request as a GET rather than POST?

Tags: c#, .net-5

I've been trying to send a POST request using [HttpClient without a body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7907648/post-an-empty-body-to-rest-api-via-httpclient/43936834) using the `PostAsync` method. However, to my utter bewildement, the request is getting sent as a `GET` and not a `POST`.

[image]

Naturally, the request fails with a `405 Method Not Allowed` becase the server doesn't allow `GET`.

Code sample:

```
var response = await new HttpClient().PostAsync("https://api.creativecommons.engineering/v1/auth_tokens/token?client_id=adsf&client_secret=asdf&grant_type=client_credentials", null);
Console.WriteLine(response.RequestMessage);
```

Produces:

```
Method: GET, RequestUri: 'https://api.creativecommons.engineering/v1/auth_tokens/token/?client_id=adsf&client_secret=asdf&grant_type=client_credentials', Version: 1.1
```

[Example in .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kgWzZW)

I've also tried using Flurl, but lead to the same result (I am guessing it is using HttpClient under the hood).

Any ideas why `PostAsync` is sending the request as a GET rather than POST?

---

## Update

This question got quite a bit of hate without offering an ounce of constructive criticism... Well done StackOverflow, really well done, so much for being more welcoming...

If you come across a similar issue, here are the three things to look for:

1. HttpClient **will automatically redirect if the response is 301 (Redirect)**. It won't return you 301 as a status code!
2. As it does the redirect it **changes the request from POST to GET**. This is [technically correct](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect), because in order to preserve the method when redirecting the server needs to return *307* and not *301*.
3. Check the address in the code against the one in the `RequestMessage`. This may be obvious in some cases, but in my case, the redirect involved adding a single `/` not something easily visible in the debugger window!

```
https://api.creativecommons.engineering/v1/auth_tokens/token?client_id=adsf&client_secret=asdf&grant_type=client_credentials
https://api.creativecommons.engineering/v1/auth_tokens/token/?client_id=adsf&client_secret=asdf&grant_type=client_credentials
                                                            ^
```

Comment: Thanks Dawid. Upvoted. Very confusing issue, especially when integration testing. I burned a lot of time, couldn't figure out why my very specific POST requests end up as GET. I left some setup steps below for integration test setup

Comment: You just saved me hours, thanks man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted null to that body, looks like it is throwing a 405 and returning some information to look into. I believe the display of "GET" is deceiving.

EDIT: Ok, so to revise:

First the post executes and receives a 301 from the server.

[image: Fiddler showing a POST with a 301 response]

Followed by a redirect to another endpoint (as a GET) with the result of 405. Thus, the net result of your request manifested as a GET with a 405. My mistake.

[image]

Comment: You need to clarify. There doesn't appear to be anything 'deceiving' about that code. A POST request, that (probably through my fault) seems to be sent as a GET, which then the server rejects (returns 405), there is no response (even with proper keys in place).

Comment: Yes, but this not not what I am asking... I understand 405 error. My question is why is PostAsync sending a GET request rather than a POST. I've changed the title just to make this clearer.

Comment: Because of the 301. Add a slash after the word token at the end of the route, right before the ? starting the query string. That will fix your issue.

Comment: Great thanks. Might be worth making it clearer in the answer that HttpClient will automatically redirect on 301 (Redirect) - apparently, without any trail to trace it back. I am surprised other people didn't run into this issue before.

Answer (score 0):

When utilizing integration testing you will run into this issue due to https `redirect` when the default startup contains this

```
var opt = new RewriteOptions().AddRedirectToHttps();
app.UseRewriter(opt);
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

It's not enough to use the `CustomWebApplicationFactory` suggestion from Microsoft. You'll have to configure your own TestServer in your *Fixture, example below

```
            const string baseUrl = "https://localhost:5001";
            const string environmentName = "Test";
            var contentRoot = Environment.CurrentDirectory;

            Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(contentRoot)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environmentName}.json", true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();
            
            var builder = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseUrls(baseUrl)
                .UseContentRoot(contentRoot)
                .UseEnvironment(environmentName)
                .UseConfiguration(Configuration)
                .UseStartup<TestStartup>();

            Server = new TestServer(builder) {BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl)};
```

Additionally if you follow DDD and have your Controllers in a different project, make sure your API project contains Assembly reference

```
services.AddControllers(options =>
                    options.Filters.Add(new HttpResponseExceptionFilter()))
                .AddApplicationPart(typeof(Startup).Assembly)
                .AddApplicationPart(typeof(MyController).Assembly);
```