# HttpClient PostAsync() not working properly

Tags: c#, .net-core, httpclient

I use `HttpClient` to obtain access token, but I got error *Method not allowed*
I tried from postman and I was able to get tokens successfully. But even though I use the `PostAsync` method of the `HttpClient` class, method `GET` appears in the response. Isn't that strange?

[image]

```
private async Task<string> GetTokenAsync(string username,string password)
        {
            string accessToken;
            var jsonInput = jsonSerializer.Serialize(new { email = username, password = password });
            var requestContent = new StringContent(jsonInput, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(@"api/user/token/obtain", requestContent);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            accessToken = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<IntegraAuth>(content).access;
            return accessToken;
        }
```

Comment: You can also attempt to setup the `HttpRequestMessage` object yourself, and set its `Method` property to `HttpMethod.Post`, and then send it out with `.SendAsync()`. This may be useful to help figure out the situation, before you try to figure out if your server is messed up like how @SupaMaggie70b mentioned

Comment: By chance, did you used to have `GetAsync` on that line and changed it? I wonder if you're debugging an older version. That *shouldn't* happen, but try Build menu -> Clean Solution and try again.

Comment: @Narish I used `SendAsync` and set `Method=HttpMethod.Post` . but the result did not change.

Comment: @GabrielLuci I cleaned and rebuild but unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: just quessing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66358024/why-does-httpclient-postasync-appear-to-be-sending-the-request-as-a-get-rather-t maybe get-post confusion because somehow content empty; actually I would check header/content/request in postman, as better to start where it works

Comment: It may be the redirect issue described in that answer above (server responds with 301 and client automatically retries with GET). Is the URL in `response.RequestMessage` different than the URL you gave it? You can try disabling auto redirect with https://stackoverflow.com/a/10647245/1202807

Comment: @user13322060 I added slash end of the requestUri(not baseAddress) and it resolved. thank you